What are the advantages of using Navigation comoponent along with Jetpack compose?
Is there a need for Navigation component with Jetpack compose? In Jetpack compose, we can move between composables function(screen level views) without needing Navigation component, so what is the reason for using Navigation component? Why are these two used together in google samples?
What are the advantages of using Navigation comoponent along with Jetpack compose?
Thanks in advance

I can think of 3 reasons:

Handling back stack
Creating deep links
Less cluttered Composables


The view models shouldn't be affected since navigation is entirely done in Compose either way. But the clutter in the composables is considerably reduced when using the navigation library.

Good point. Updated the answer.
